# getById function the takes one or multiple key within the repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-2.2

So I am using the repository pattern with asp.net core and entity framework 6 to access database from a service layer. The issue is that I have an entity that has a composite key and the generic repository takes an int as parameter so I can't pass multiple variables to find().

I tried changing int to object and sending object with 2 ids when I need to but that doesn't seem to work.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class 
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById( int id);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Create(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you define generic repository like `IRepository<TKey, TEntity>` in order to extend possible key usage scenarios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it same signature of find method

```
public virtual TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues);
```

which accept key values as `params` of type `object`

so it will be

```
T GetById(params object[] keyValues);
```

so in this case it will accept any count of primary keys of any type

e.g.

```
new customerRepo().GetById(123)
new customerRepo().GetById(123,1)
```

and so on

Comment: that woud work but i have to ovveride the getbyId function for some repositories in order to include related tables  and the params object[]  is not working even if i try to convert to  int

Comment: this is my current code with the overriden getByiid       Context.UserSkills.SingleOrDefault(userSkill => userSkill.UserSkillId == Convert.ToInt32(userSkillId));

Comment: first you should change it in main interface IRepository<T> to be same signature of find function then  override getByiid to be Context.UserSkills.find(keyValues); no need to do any conversion just pass parameters from overridden function to find function directly

Comment: would this also apply to an Add(T entity) method which is supposed to return a key? so, instead of returning int, would it return object[]?